# Is it possible to derive from and "respecialize" a specialized class with a type that derives from the specializing type?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization, derived-class

### Simplified Question

I have the following:

```
class Foo {};
class Bar : public Foo {};

template <class T>
class TemplatedClass   : public T {};
class SpecializedClass : public TemplatedClass<Foo> {};
```

I need a new class,

```
class RespecializedClass : public TemplatedClass<Bar> {};
```

but this new class is in every way identical to `SpecializedClass` except that it specializes on `Bar`, a class that derives from `Foo`. It *would* work to simply copy-paste `SpecializedClass`, but then I'd have to maintain two codelines that are meant to be identical.

Is there a way to *derive* `RespecializedClass` from `SpecializedClass`, but further specializing the templating datatype to a child datatype?

### Original Question (closer to my actual problem)

I'm given the following hierarchy of classes:

```
class X {};

class A {};

template <class T>
class B : public T, public A {};

class C : public B<X> {};

class D : public C {};
```

I can't touch any of the source behind `X`, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. I can only derive from and extend them.

Now, I've derived a new class from `X`—call it lowercase `x`. (I normally wouldn't use `X` and `x` in one setting but in this case the visual similarity is helpful in this case.)

```
class x : public X {};
```

What I need is a class that's identical to `D`, but templated on `x` instead of `X`.

Of course, I can simply copy-paste `C` and `D` and specialize them to `x` like so:

```
class c : public B<x> {};
class d : public c {};
```

But then I'd have to maintain this codeline whenever `C` and `D` are modified.

Is there a way to do something like

```
class d : public D, public B<x> {};
```

to "respecialize" the template's datatype further up in the hierarchy?

#### Note

*No need to read this paragraph; in fact it may confuse more than enlighten.* The reason I need `d` to be templated on `x` and not `X` is that `x` and `X` encapsulate database tables, and `B` has been written to update whatever table it's templated on. To get closer to the truth, the infrastructure I'm working with autogenerates encapsulation classes for all our database tables. In the database dictionary, one may configure "derived" tables that inherit all fields and keys from another table, then extend this table with additional fields and keys. The infrastructure not only autogenerates encapsulation classes for these "derived" tables too, but actually represents them as derived classes of their respective parent classes. So, in truth I'm not actually *coding* `x`—it is being autogenerated for me, as a child class of `X`. What I need, now that I can be more precise, is a class that is does *everything* `D` does, exactly, but operates on the database table `x`, not `X`.

Comment: Why don't you want to make `C` and `D` (or its copies) class templates with one type parameter (`class T`)?

Comment: `X`, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are all part of my company's infrastructure, unfortunately. I can derive and extend those classes, but not modify them. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: So, in essence, you would want both d and D to derive from the same interface, in order to be able to use d in place of D for some algorithm?

Comment: @didierc - I think that's a valid way of putting it. But not only do I want the same interface, _but the same code_. That is, any code that works for `X`, should work for `x` too, right? I actually have no need to modify `D`'s code whatsoever. I only need that `T` to be specialized because there is some code in `B` (again, out of my reach) that will write to one database table if it's specialized on `X`, or another database table if it's specialized on `x`. (See the note for more details.)

Comment: The only way for any code to work on both d and D is if they share te same ancestry (which could be either class too) AND that code works on that common ancestor. Since your framework doesn't care about table "commonalities", and you cannot get that out of the box in C++ (afaik): you must either implement an adapter class which will expose the common interface and wrap D or d, OR write templated code on that interface.

Comment: If you want both d and D to share the same code, you need to change your framework, I don't think C++ allows you to redefine a class.

Comment: Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, though regardless you may be correct that there's no way to do this in C++, the code is always working with `D`, so as long as `d` derives from `D`, everything should work. Similarly, the code _inside_ `D` is always working with `X`, never `x`, so whether the object being handled is `X` or `x`, everything should work. It's precisely these reasons, _that all code below `B` will deal with the generic classes `D` and `X`,_ that I believed "respecialization" to be possible.

Comment: So the only possible solution for you is really templated code: you devise all your algorithms as templates which act on an hypothetic T carrying that conmon interface between d and D (which is actually D, but you don't want to make it D explicitely). Then you may use that code on either class, though at some upper layer the code path will have to be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to derive RespecializedClass from SpecializedClass, but further specializing the templating datatype to a child datatype?

**No.** At least, not with the constraint that you cannot touch the implementation of `SpecializedClass`.
If you *could* change it, you should change it like this:

old code:

```
template <class T>
class TemplatedClass   : public T {};
class SpecializedClass : public TemplatedClass<Foo> {};
```

new code:

```
template <class T>
class TemplatedClass   : public T {};
template<type Base = Foo> // << HERE
class SpecializedClass : public TemplatedClass<Base> {};
```

since you cannot do this, you are left with the following possibilities:

- roll your own SpecializedClass: as you said, copy SpecializedClass into your own specialization (similar to "new code" above, then add: `using RespecializedClass = SpecializedClass<Bar>;`). Then, maintain all code using the new SpecializedClass (call it RespecializedClass directly? :)) and ignore the one provided by the original library. You will have to propagate fixes and patches from the original code to your own copy though :(
- propose a patch to the original maintainers in the company, explaining your concrete need. If you provide a default template argument for `Base`, client code accross the company could work without any changes required.

Comment: I made a local copy of the code I can't touch, just to try this solution. However I've run into some problems. First, I take it you meant `typename`, not `type`? Second, I'm changing _only_ one line for now—formerly `class SpecializedClass : public TemplatedClass<Foo>`—now `template<typename Base = Foo> class SpecializedClass : public TemplatedClass<Base>`. However I get the compilation error, _"Error: No parameters provided for template."_, at lines such as these: `const char *SpecializedClass::className  = "SpecializedClass";`. Is it because templated classes can't have static members?

Comment: You have to instantiate the static member like this: `template<typename Base> const char * SpecializedClass<Base>::className = "SpecializedClass";`.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to minimize code duplication, I think the easiest way, without meddling with your ORM library inheritance tree, is to write your shareable code as templates. Your templates will be able to make the assumptions you need on the types they manipulate (interface similar to the one of `D`).

Now, regarding the simplified statement of the problem, if the methods of the class you wish to respecialize are declared virtuals in `TemplatedClass`, it should not be a problem to derive by hand `SpecializedClass` from both `TemplatedClass<Bar>` and `SpecializedClass`, and do the correct inner plumbing. Otherwise, you won't be able to use `RespecializedClass` in place of `SpecializedClass`. The remaining solution would be to create an adapter class for these, and write your code for the adapter, or use the templated code solution from the beginning of this post.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! Still thinking things through.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean. I have the impression that something must be possible (it's the template effect). I'll think about it some more as well.

Answer (score 1):

Given your hierarchy:

```
class X {};
class A {};
template <class T> class B : public T, public A {};
class C : public B<X> {};
class D : public C {};
```

you could make every subclass of B also a class template:

```
template <class T> class CT: public B<T> {};
template <class T> class DT: public C<T> {};
```

The class templates `CT` and `DT` are under your control, so you can specialize them for `T==x`. Just to test, define a few template aliases that are equal to your old classes `C` and `D`:

```
using class CX = C<X>; // equal to your old C
using class DX = D<X>; // equal to your old D
```

and then you need two more typedefs to get the classes that you require:

```
using class Cx = C<x>;
using class Dx = D<x>;
```